# How to insert null to certain columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a table which has 15 columns in it and a proc fills in only 7 columns. Now it has been asked to insert NULL to all other columns. The column definition cant be changed. Is there any way to put NULL other than specifying each column and value as NULL in the insert statement. The database is oracle 12

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You just need enumerate the target columns in the `insert` statement, excluding those that you don't want to provide values for. Oracle will assign the default value of each column (or `null` if there is no default).

Say you have the following table:

```
create table mytable (
    col1 int not null primary key, 
    col2 int not null, 
    col3 int default 0,  -- has a default 
    col4 int,            -- has no default
    col5 int
);
```

You can do:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2)
values (1, 2);
```

And you get:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5
---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
   1 |    2 |    0 | null | null
```

Of course if any of the column is defined as `not null` and has no default, this will fail with error `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ...`.